# How to handle concurrent DB connections by multiple users using PDO in PHP5

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use PDO in my application. However I am confused regarding the use of PDO here. Because my application access target will be multiple users. Lets say 100 users in simultaneously . So, as I read about PDO it will create 100 db connections to access. This can create a problem as it will limit on concurrent connections allowed by Server. And new users will get connection error.

How can I use PDO such a way that it handles the concurrent connections and does not overhead?

Comment: I think you mis-understand how it works - do a bit of googling but believe me PDO will handle 500 concurrent users on even a modest server without breaking a sweat.

Comment: doesn't this mostly depend on the database itself rather then the application?

Comment: PDO can handle many copnnections as it gets.. however MySQL server has limited openn connnections on shared hostings. As in PDO, we are not sure when the connection being closed...so it will overhead the active connections...

Comment: If you are expecting 100 *concurrent* users, maybe you're beyond shared hosting. If your shared host doesn't offer this, your own private server can: connection pooling using any number of different strategies, depending on your database (e.g. I'm a fan of pgbouncer for Postgres).

Answer (score 2):

100 concurrent users is not that impressive number though. Taken average user makes a click once a minute, we have 100 connects for 60 seconds, which makes 1.5 connects / second.
A sanely written app should perform no longer 0,1 sec. means 10 connections could be fit in one second. and we have 1.5.

Yes, it can peak sometimes, but anyway, number of allowed connections would be the last thing I would think of. Most likely your database will be killed far earlier than limit reached - due to improper indexing and architecture.

Comment: 100 users is just an assumption. My point is as I read baout PDO, it just opens up new connections if not found any idle connection.. this way we will come up a point where active connection are increased to MYSQL max. connection supported level.

So is there any way where we can overcome with these possibilities using PDO .

Also I am not able to see information regarding the life cycle of a PDO connection.

Comment: most likely you confused PDO with persistent connections.

Comment: ok.. so you meant to say, if I use PDO with non-persistent, I will not come up with above situation.. Please correct me if I wrong.

PDO non-persistent life cycle:
1) scripts starts - getconnection
2) connection active
3) scripts end - connection close.


Now, for new scripts there will be new connection establish.

Comment: Yes. Although PDO *can* be set up into persistent mode, as it said in the other answer, but by default it behaves exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use persistent connections. Instead of closing and reopening, PDO will return you unused connections. This should reduce overhead and also amount of opened connections.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: "and also amount of opened connections" is a pure fantasy, nowhere it is following from the previous statement. yet one can tell from it that there are "unused" - i.e. - **occupied** connections

Comment: Unfortunately, on this blessed site we cannot trust to the voting mechanism on the matters that are slightest beyond basic syntax issues

Comment: @YourCommonSense please correct me, I would like to learn something new too